# Using variables versus pointers to variables as parameters for a function

Tags: c++, c, pointers, parameters

When a function requires a pointer as an argument (and not the variable that the pointer references), is this simply because of the size of the values that would be passed to the function?

I can understand how someone would want to pass a pointer to an array or struct, rather than passing the entire array or struct, but are their other reasons for this decision? For example, a function requiring a pointer to an `int` (4 bytes) rather than the `int` (4 bytes) itself.

Comment: Try writing a function that swaps two values, so `int a = 1, b = 2; "swap(a, b);"`, so that afterwards `a == 2 && b == 1`.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  For example, in C++ you can pass parameters by reference where as in C you can't.

Comment: passing a pointer to anything will actually be 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like your function to change the value of a parameter (such as an `int`), then you must pass in a pointer to it. Otherwise, any changes that your function makes will be made on a copy.

In general, so-called "output parameters" in C and C++ are often pointers to whatever variable is to be affected by the function.

As for arrays, C doesn't actually permit one to pass a large block of memory to a function, and so we have no choice but to pass a pointer.

(Edit: as discussed in the comments, this answer applies to pointers only. In C++, one may also use references)

Comment: Small nit: `struct`s can be quite sizable chunks of memory, and `struct`s can be function arguments, so C does allow to pass a large block of memory to a function. It just doesn't allow to pass arrays.

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks. Since it's almost always a bad idea to do this, I wasn't thinking of it.

Comment: Can a parameter be passed by reference if the function wants to change the value of the parameter?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: if the function needs to change the variable in the calling function, then the variable must be passed by reference to the function.  If changes made by the function should not change the variable in the calling function, then (a copy of) the variable should be passed by value to the function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: This answer says "you must pass in a pointer", but in C++ there is also the option to pass by reference.  I was hoping that Nigel would answer my comment.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, of course in C++ you also have the option of using references. As you probably know, there are pros and cons to using refernces or pointers. Seemed like this question was posed specifically about the pointer option so I ran with that one.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you would pass built in types by value except when you want to modify them in the method or function and have the modification apply to the original variable.

You can pass by reference or by pointer. Some people prefer to pass by pointer if they are going to modify the input as it is more explicit as you have to dereference the pointer.

IE:

```
void foo(int& a, int* b)
{
    a = 1; // This modifies the external variable, but you can't see that just looking at this line
    *b = 1; //explicitly modifying external variable
}

int z = 0;
int y = 0;
foo(y, &z); //z is explicitly being allowed to be modified, that y can be too isn't apparent until you look at the function declaration.
```

Others think this passing pointers is ugly and don't like it.

The best practice for passing large types around is by const reference, which says you won't be modifying the instance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in one line is: pass-by-(pointer/reference)-to-const if you are dealing with input parameters to non fundamental types, pass-by-value if you are dealing with input parameters to fundamental types, pass-by-(pointer/reference) otherwise. As pointed out in the comments (thanks TonyD) this last "rule" is meant to be an optimisation over using pass-by-(pointer/reference)-to-const; it is likely unnecessary, but it's worth nowing. Note that passing by reference to const does not inficiate the ability to call a function with a temporary (be it a literal or a result from a function call) parameter.

Several distinctions have to made to answer this question appropriately. First of all C and C++ are two different beasts: the only options in C are pass-by-value (pbv), pass-by-pointer (pbp) and pass-by-pointer-to-const (pbptc). In C++ you have also the option to pass-by-reference (pbr) and pass-by-reference-to-const (pbrtc). Secondly, there is the distinction between an input parameter and an (input/)output parameter; when a parameter belongs to the second class you have no options but pbp or pbr (if appliable, i.e. if using c++). As for input parameters, the considerations to be made are more subtle. Alexandrescu addresses this issue in his book "Modern C++"

> you sometimes need to answer the following question: Given an
>   arbitrary type T, what is  the most efficient way of passing and
>   accepting objects of type T as arguments to functions? In general, the
>   most efficient way is to pass elaborate types by reference and scalar
>   types by value. (Scalar types consist of  the arithmetic types
>   described earlier as well as enums, pointers, and pointers to
>   members.) For elaborate  types you avoid the overhead of an extra
>   temporary (constructor-plus-destructor calls), and for scalar types 
>   you avoid the overhead of the indirection resulting from the
>   reference.

(of course, for input parameters, he is referring to pbrtc). Similarly, you should choose to pbptc for "elaborate" types in C.

Finally, if you are using C++, you can automate this choice by using "type traits" (either the [standard ones](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/) or custom written ones, see Modern C++ for more on this). Type traits allow you to automatically know if a type is a fundamental type, if it is a reference already (in which case you cannot pass it by reference, because C++ doesn't allow references to references) and all kind of meaningful stuff. By means of `type_traits`, for example, you can write something like this

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef int& my_type;

void f(const std::add_lvalue_reference<my_type> a){
}

typedef int my_type2;

void g(const std::add_lvalue_reference<my_type2> a){
}

int main() {

}
```

Of course, this is a made up example, but you can see the utility of the approach, which is much greater if you are using templates. Notice that `type_traits` are part of the c++11 std library, if you are not using c++11 you have to make your own (or use some library as [loki](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/TypeTraits.h?view=markup))

Comment: The "pass-by-value if you are dealing with input parameters to fundamental types" was faddish a few years back, culminating in a burst of interest in type traits to achieve it in templates, but in practice it's a pain when function parameter types are variable through template parameters, and using `const T&` even for fundamental types is *extremely* rarely a performance issue (especially with optimisation enabled). So, the whole type traits thing is worth knowing as for selective use but not as a standard practice: too fiddly, error prone and obfuscating.

Comment: @TonyD you are probably right, the additional indirection (admitting it does reach the compiled code) is most likely not going to be the bottleneck. I'm editing the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the `int` variable, you can use reference too.

For an array, the array name is just a pointer to the first element, when it's used as a parameter passed to a function, it will change to ordinary pointer, so you must pass the number of the elements in the array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Using variables versus pointers to variables as parameters for a function

General recommendations:

1. If a function does not change parameter, pass by value.

   ```
     #include <iostream>
     int test(int arg){
         std::cout << arg;
     }

     int main(int argc, char** argv){
         int a = 6;
         test(a);
         return 0;
     }
   ```
2. If a function needs to change passed parameter, pass by reference.

   ```
     #include <iostream>
     int test(int &arg){
         arg = 6;
     }

     int main(int argc, char** argv){
         int a = 0;
         test(a);
         std::cout << arg;
         return 0;
     }
   ```
3. If a function does not need to change parameter, but parameter is BIG, pass by const reference.
4. If a function neeeds to change passed parameter AND this parameter is optional, pass by pointer.

   ```
     #include <iostream>
     int test(int *arg){
         if (arg)
             *arg = 6;
     }

     int main(int argc, char** argv){
         int a = 0, b = 1;
         test(0);
         test(&b);
         std::cout << a << std::endl << b << std::endl;
         return 0;
     }
   ```
5. If a function does not neeed to change passed parameter, parameter is big and parameter is optional, pass by pointer to const.

Reasoning: references and pointers can be used to modify values "outside" of function, but references cannot be set to 0/NULL.

> pointer to an int (4 bytes)

Depending on the platform, pointer to int may not be 4 bytes big. On 64bit system it'll be 8bytes big, for example.

Returning pointer to int makes sense if that function allocates memory block. Returning pointer/reference to int makes sense if this function is is used as a "selector" and you need to write into returned value.

```
#include <iostream>
int& getMaxVal(int &a, int &b){
     return (a > b)? a: b;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
      int i = 3, j = 4;
      std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
      getMaxVal(i, j) /= 2;
      std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
      return 0;
}
```